# Highcharts histogram dosen show right results

Tags: javascript, highcharts, histogram

I'm using highcharts histogram plot and it looks like it doesn’t work right way. In the picture you can see the plot and the data. Like you see the highest number it data set is -10, but the histogram ends in -25. And for some reason it adds dose highest values to the blue charts( the middle one). Any idea what is going on here? 
[image]
Here is the code:

```
function Get_results(year, chart){
  var event_colors ={"O_liig":"#3f51b5",
                    "N_liig": "#ff5722",
                    "K_liig": "#03a9f4"}
    $.getJSON(link, function(event_data) {
        var histomgra_data_events = {};
        var liig = "-";
        $.each(event_data,function(i,val){
          if (val[1].startsWith("N")){
            liig = val[1];
          }
          else if (val[1].startsWith("O")){
            liig = "O_liig";
          }
          else if (val[1].startsWith("K")){
            liig = "K_liig";
          }
          if (histomgra_data_events[liig]  === undefined){
            histomgra_data_events[liig] = [];
          }
          histomgra_data_events[liig].push(val[0]);
        });
        var histogram_plot = [];
        $.each(histomgra_data_events,function(i,val){
          else if (i == "O_liig"){
            histogram_plot.push({name: i +" (" + val.length + ")", type: 'histogram',baseSeries: 's1', color:event_colors[i], xAxis: 1, yAxis: 0, baseSeries: i,zIndex: -1,},{type: 'scatter',id: i, data:val, visible: false, showInLegend: false});
          }
          else if (i == "K_liig"){
            histogram_plot.push({name: i +" (" + val.length + ")", type: 'histogram',baseSeries: 's1', color:event_colors[i], xAxis: 1, yAxis: 1, baseSeries: i,zIndex: -1,},{type: 'scatter',id: i, data:val, visible: false, showInLegend: false});
          }
          else {
            histogram_plot.push({name: i +" (" + val.length + ")", type: 'histogram',baseSeries: 's1', color:event_colors[i], xAxis: 1, yAxis: 2, baseSeries: i,zIndex: -1,},{type: 'scatter',id: i, data:val, visible: false, showInLegend: false});
          }
        });
        update_chart(histogram_plot);
   });
};

function update_chart(data){
  var colors = Highcharts.getOptions().colors;
  Highcharts.chart('Event_histogram', {
    title: {
        text: ''
    },
    credits:{enabled:false},
    xAxis: [{
        title: { text: '' },
    }, {
        alignTicks: false,
        min: -130,
        max: 0,
    },
    ],
    legend: {
              enabled : ($(window).width() > 768)
    },

    yAxis: [{
        title: { text: '' },
        height: '33.33%',
        offset:0,
    }, {
        height: '28.33%',
        top: '38.33%',
        offset:0,
    },{
        title: { text: '' },
        height: '28.33%',
        top: '71.66%',
        offset:0,
    }],
    series: data,
    plotOptions: {
      histogram: {
          borderRadius: 2,
          borderColor: '#222846',
        }
    },
});
}
```

EDIT: Here is JSFiddle link https://jsfiddle.net/sjzf32t4/1/

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle example please?

Comment: Could you reproduce your case with some static data on some online editor which I could work on?

Comment: I edit the text and there is now jsfiddle example

Comment: After a deeper investigation, I found that it is a regression. I reported it on Highcharts Github issue channel where you can follow the thread and ask core developers for the workaround if you need it. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/13069